# Fastest way to build numpy array from sum of coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have a list (or numpy.array) of `(row, col)` coordinates, e.g.:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 0)]
```

I'd like to build the 2x2 array like this:

```
2 0
0 1
```

where each of the listed coordinates is counted and put in the right place in the array. I.e. `(0, 0)` appears twice, so `a[0, 0] == 2`.

I know I can build this by iterating and poking the array for each element, but I wanted to check if there is any support in numpy regarding building the array like this, mostly for performance reasons. Can you point me in the right direction if so?

Also, is there a reduce-like functionality along the above lines? I.e. do `new = f(acc, el)` instead of `new = acc + el`.

Comment: Added some timing to my answer. I did not expect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move to flat indexing and use `np.bincount`.

```
>>> import numpy as np                                                   
>>>                                                                                                                 
>>> coords = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 0)]                                       
>>> 
>>> shp = np.max(coords, axis=0) + 1     
>>> flt = np.ravel_multi_index(np.moveaxis(coords, -1, 0), shp)               
>>> result = np.bincount(flt, minlength=shp.prod()).reshape(shp)                         
>>>                                                                                                                 
>>> result                                                                                                          
array([[2, 0],                                                                                                      
       [0, 1]])
```

**EDIT** As pointed out by @MikeMiller `moveaxis` is overkill here; `np.transpose(coords)` or if coords happen to be an array `coords.T` is better. `moveaxis` would be more general if `coords` were for some reason more than `2D` but that doesn't look like a likely scenario.

Comment: Do you think `np.transpose(coords)` is slightly clearer than `np.moveaxis(coords, -1, 0)`?

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks, I updated the post.

Comment: Thanks @PaulPanzer!

Answer (score 2):

Using [`np.unique()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to count the number of unique coordinates ( <s>however, I don't know this is the fastest way or not</s>, it is not, see the timings below):

```
import numpy as np

a = [(0,0), (1,1), (1,0), (0,0)]

b = np.array(a)
u, c = np.unique(b, axis=0, return_counts=True)
m = np.max(b)+1
ans = np.zeros((m, m))
ans[u[:,0], u[:,1]] = c

# ans
array([[ 2.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.]])
```

---

I did some timing:

```
# data preparation
max_coord = 10000
max_size = 100000

# this is awful, I know it can be done much better...
coords = [(int(np.random.randint(max_coord, size=1)),
           int(np.random.randint(max_coord, size=1))) for _ in range(max_size)]

# timings using %timeit

# my solution
139 ms ± 592 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# Paul Panzer's solution
142 ms ± 461 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# with max_size = 1000000
# my solution
827 ms ± 19.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# Paul's solution
748 ms ± 4.62 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Almost the same (though I don't know about their memory footprint; with `max_size=1000000` and `max_coord=100000` both solutions give `MemoryError` on my machine). However, I'll go with the @Paul's solution, it is much more neat (and faster when data is big).